# How to access an override function into another script (Unity C#)

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

This is my script

**WebSocketNetwork:**

```
public override void GametableHistory(bool success, Int32 gametable_no, Int32 year, Int32 month, Int32 day, Int32 shoe_no, bc_gametable_history_list list)
{
    Debug.Log("GametableHistory gametable_history_list.Count = " + list.Count);

    string s = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
    {
        s += list[i].r;
        s += ",";
    }
    Debug.Log("Gametable " + gametable_no + " History = " + s);
    //PK 4/23/2018
    PlayInfo.Instance.gametablehistory = s;
}
```

**WebsocketSession:**

```
abstract public void GametableHistory (bool success, Int32 gametable_no, Int32 year, Int32 month, Int32 day, Int32 shoe_no, gametable_history_list list);
```

**PlayInfo.cs:**

```
public string gametablehistory;
```

and i have a blank script which is **TestScript.cs** . What i want here is that on my `TestScript.cs` i will call the override function and get the `gametable_history_list` but i don't know how should i get it from there. Could someone please guide me.

Comment: I guess this is not a duplicate @Programmer

Comment: *"access an override function into another script"* Which part is not a duplicate? You want to access  the GametableHistory from another script?

Comment: I want to get the specific variable there sir . `gametable_history_list` could you please help me out?

Comment: See my answer from the other question which also show example of how to access variable (`playerScore`) in `ScriptA` from another script(`ScriptB`). Just read that.